# How can i validate my questions in Python?

Tags: python

stackoverflow!

I need some help with my code.
I need to create simple question/answer app.

What I want to achieve is -
When a user comes to: **Do you have any suggestions?** question
I can answer **Yes** or **No**. If I click **Yes**, I get all the questions again. If I press **No**, I get this message: **Thanks for your time!**

I've tried a lot of options, but all I can achieve is showing me - **Thanks for your time!**  selecting both Yes and No.

I bet my code is bad, but im new in python..

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

d2 = today.strftime("%d, %Y\n")
print("Today is:", d2)

print("Welcome to my App!")
print("Subtitle here!\n")

def example():
    while True:
        name = input("Greetings!\nWhat is your name?\n ")
        description = input("Describe yourself:\n ")
        city = input("Where do you live?\n ")
        address = input("Your birthdate:\n ")

        try:
            question = int(input("Do you have any suggestions?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n" ))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error! This is not a number. Try again.")

        else:
            print("Thanks for your time!")
            break

example()

if question == "yes": 
    print("Fill the questions again!")
elif question == "no": 
    print("Thanks for your time!")
```

Comment: What, in your own words, does this line do `question = int(input("Do you have any suggestions?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n" ))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly fixing up your code:

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

d2 = today.strftime("%d, %Y\n")
print("Today is:", d2)

print("Welcome to my App!")
print("Subtitle here!\n")

def example():
    while True:
        name = input("Greetings!\nWhat is your name?\n ")
        description = input("Describe yourself:\n ")
        city = input("Where do you live?\n ")
        address = input("Your birthdate:\n ")

        try:
            question = int(input("Do you have any suggestions?\nAnswer with: 1 = Yes, 2 = No\n" ))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error! This is not a number. Try again.")
            continue

        if question == 1:
            print("Fill the questions again!")
            continue
        elif question == 2:
            print("Thanks for your time!")
            break
        else:
            print("That number is not a valid option. Try again!")

example()
```

Comment: Im dumb, ty, Andrew.